# Given a SSH tunnel A-B-C, how to exclude B?

Tags: ssh

I have been using a 3-machine (`A`, `B`, `C`) SSH setup for a while. Both `A` and `C` are machines on two different LAN that I want to connect and `B` is my own box with a public address.

On machine `A` I do this:

```
ssh -p 443 -f -N -R 1987:localhost:22 hostname-of-B
```

On machine `C` I have this in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host hostB
  User user-of-B
  HostName hostname-of-B

Host hostA
  User user-of-A
  ProxyCommand ssh -o 'GatewayPorts yes' -q hostB nc -q0 localhost 1987
```

So I can connect from `C` to `A` with:

```
ssh hostA
```

This setup worked fine, until I had to switch `B` to another machine with a worse internet connection.  Now everything is super-slow, even though `A` and `C` have an excellent connection.

So I wonder if it's possible, after establishing the initial connection from `C` to `A` through `B`, to establish a direct connection from `A` to `C`. Thus taking `B` out of the equation and making the connection fast again.

Comment: Is A directly reachable via ssh from C?

Comment: No, as I said, both A and C are on two different LAN; they have no public address.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. You need something public to forward through. Or for each connection visibility of one server from the other.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious. Your answer does not prove that it's impossible though.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably avoid the slow B if you have any other machine X which has public ssh access. This could be your machine at home or a very cheap rented public virtual machine with good connection.

On C you can open a reverse tunnel from X back to C:

```
ssh -Nf -R 10022:localhost:22  user-of-X@hostname-of-X
```

Then on A you add another "hop-config" via X

```
Host hostAviaX
  User user-of-X
  ProxyCommand ssh -o 'GatewayPorts yes'-q hostB nc -q0 localhost 10022
```

and on A `ssh hostAviaX` should work.

Note if A is *your* client machine in a network where you are controlling the router you could enable port forwarding so that A has public ssh access. In this case you would not need another X and you could replace X == A in the example above.

Comment: So your answer is 'Replace B with a faster X, which is like B in every way, except faster'?